# How can I make "select all" and "unselect all" buttons using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a "AlertDialog" with a Checklist (CheckboxListTile) and I wanted to add two buttons at the top. One with the option "Select All" and the other "Unselect All". How can I implement these two buttons that handles the state of all the items in the list?

Comment: It comes down to how do you handle each selected item, for example if you create an array of selected items, select all simply adds all items to selected_items array and unselect all will simply clear the selected items array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's assume that you have loads of checkboxes and you assign a value to each of them

```dart
List<bool> checkBoxValues;

...

CheckBox(
  value: checkBoxValues[0] // or i if you automate this
)
```

Then you can easily set all values by

```dart
CupertinoButton(
  child: Text("check all"),
  onPressed: () {
    setState (() {
      for (var i = 0; I checkBoxValues.length < ; i++)
        checkBoxValues[i] = true;
    });
  },
)
```

Comment: Cool. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: if this helped, accepting or upvoting the answer would be nice :-)